# "Points To Raster Tool"- Output pixel values differ from original point values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, convert, point

I am trying to convert an evenly spaced set of points to a raster using the "Points To Raster" tool in 10.1. 
Problem: Generally, the raster makes sense, but in some areas the cell values differ quite significantly from the original point values (e.g. point= 0, raster cell= 87).
I have already tried different cell sizes and assignment types (although I would like the MEAN).
Would anyone know why that is and what I need to do in order to obtain "meaningful" values (cell values that represent the original point values).

Comment: Maybe provide more details about your data set(s) and the objective for using the **Point to Raster** conversion tool.